# How to improve the speed of this awk script

Tags: awk

I have a large file, say `file1.log`, that looks like this:

```
1322 a@gmail.com
2411 b@yahoo.com
```

and a smaller file, say `file2.log`, that looks like this:

```
a@gmail.com
c@yahoo.com
```

In fact, `file1.log` contains about 6500000 lines and `file2.log` contains about 140000.

I want to find all lines in `file2.log` that do not appear in `file1.log`. I wrote this awk command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$2]++} NR!=FNR && c[$1]==0 {print $0}' file1.log file2.log > result.log'
```

after half an hour or so I find the command is still running, and `less result.log` shows that `result.log` is empty.
I am wondering whether there is something I can do to do the job quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash the smaller file `file2` into memory. Remember [*Tao of Programming*, 1.3](https://www.mit.edu/~xela/tao.html): *How could it be otherwise?*:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {           # hash file2 since its smaller
    a[$0]
    next
}
($2 in a) {         # if file1 entry found in hash
    delete a[$2]    # remove it
}
END {               # in the end
    for(i in a)     # print the ones that remain in the hash
        print i
}' file2 file1      # mind the order
```

Output:

```
c@yahoo.com
```

Comment: yes, it is much quicker. real 3.051s user 2.734s sys 0.281s

Answer (score 1):

If you sort the files, you can use `comm` to print only those lines present in the second file with:

```
comm -13 <(awk '{ print $2 }' file1.log | sort) <(sort file2.log)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I test it and it is slower than those awk competitors.

Comment: `cut -d' ' -f2 file1.log` should be much faster than `awk '{ print $2 }' file1.log` since `cut` doesn't have to analyze the input and assign variables (NR, FNR, NF, $0, $1, etc.) like awk does.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest is just a simple `grep`-pipeline

```
grep -Fwof file2 file1 | grep -Fwovf - file2
```

you can also just extract the second column of `file1` and use the last part of the above command again:

```
awk '{print $2}' file1 | grep -Fwovf - file2
```

Or everything in a single awk:

```
awk '(NR==FNR){a[$2]; next}!($1 in a)' file1 file2
```